# Having trouble with Textile PHP parser for MarkItUp

Tags: php, parsing, textile, markitup

I've created a Jekyll based blog using Textile markdown, and I was working on creating an editor using [Markitup](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) I am having a heck of a time getting the php textile parser to work so I can see the preview. I've downloaded the [Textile Official PHP Parser](http://textile.thresholdstate.com/), and just can't seem to figure it out.

I've found numerous examples on how to use Markdown but examples for using Textile seem to be a little slim.

Here is the code to use Markdown:

```
<?php
include_once "markdown.php";
$html=Markdown($_POST['data']);
echo htmlentities($html); \
?>
```

And the example.php from the Textile Official PHP Parser:

```
<?php
require_once('classTextile.php');
$textile = new Textile();
$in = <<<EOF
A *simple* example.
EOF;
echo $textile->TextileThis($in);
?>
```

And this is what I've clobbered together on my own:

```
<?php
require_once ('classTextile.php');
$textile = new Textile();
echo $textile->TextileThis($_POST['data']);
?>
```

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Would be very grateful for any help, I normally don't code websites, I just keep the servers running :)

Thanks!!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the Textile code there, what exactly is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Answer, just in case anyone else is looking for this, the last example I posted:

```
<?php
require_once ('classTextile.php');
$textile = new Textile();
echo $textile->TextileThis($_POST['data']);
?>
```

Works perfectly, just as long as your path is part of open_basedir

derp.